# Proof about the minimum distance to a plane

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

How would you use Lagrange multipliers to show that the minimum distance to a plane is given by:
$$\frac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
for $P=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and the normal vector $n=(a,b,c)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741519/use-lagrange-multipliers-to-show-the-distance-from-a-point-to-a-plane

does this bring you further?

Answer (score 1):

Let define $f\colon(x,y,z)\mapsto(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2$ and $g\colon (x,y,z)\mapsto ax+by+cz+d$, then:
$$\nabla_{(x,y,z)}f=2(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0),\nabla_{(x,y,z)}g=(a,b,c).$$
Therefore, if $(x,y,z)$ is a critical point of $f$ such that $g(x,y,z)=0$, one gets:
$$(a,b,c)^{\perp}\subseteq(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)^{\perp}.$$
In other words, there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)=(\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c).$$
In particular, one has:
$$\begin{align}f(x,y,z)&=\lambda^2(a^2+b^2+c^2),\\a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)&=\lambda(a^2+b^2+c^2).\end{align}$$
Hence, since $g(x,y,z)=0$, namely $ax+by+cz=-d$, one gets:
$$\lambda=-\frac{ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$
This finally leads to:
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{(ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$
Whence the result taking the square root.

**Remark.** This method requires that somehow you have proved that the minimum exists, all I have shown is that $f$ has at most one critical point on $\{g=0\}$ and characterize it.